# linq mysql query into int array

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm still very new in my linq skills.  I have a mysql query that returns 3 records, each record is an int.  I want to stick those ints into an array.  I thought I could make it easy on myself and do that with a linq command instead of creating a reader and looping through the results.
Here is my code:

```
query = "SELECT cic.catid FROM cart_item ci LEFT JOIN cart_item_category cic USING (itemref) WHERE ci.pid = @pid";

try
{
    item.catIDs = con.Query(query, new { pid = ImId}).ToArray();
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{

}
```

I am getting the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'dynamic[]' to 'int[]'`

I'm assuming my linq query is not correct.

Comment: try `new int[] { pid = ImId }`. You create a dynamic type when you do `new { pid = ImId }` or make `item.catIDs` a `dynamic[]`

Comment: or is there not con.Query<int>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
con.Query(...
```

try using

```
con.Query<int>(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like catIds is array of integer, But you are trying to assign anonymous collection to integer which is not correct.

Please try the below code. I think it should work

```
query = "SELECT cic.catid FROM cart_item ci LEFT JOIN cart_item_category cic USING (itemref) WHERE ci.pid = @pid";

try
{
    item.catIDs = con.Query(query, Convert.ToInt32(ImId)).ToArray();
}
catch(MySqlException ex)
{

}
```